# Hidden Field in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have hidden field in gridview. I do not get the value in code behind. 
 It works fine without MasterPage and Ajax, can you help me to get a value in code behind. 
Thanks

```
protected void empgrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "UpdateEmployee")
            {

                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                GridViewRow row = empgrid.Rows[index];

                Session["Employee"] = ((HiddenField)empgrid.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("EmployeeID")).Value;


                Response.Redirect("UpdateEmployee.aspx");

            }

        }
```

---

```
<%@ Page  EnableEventValidation = "false"  Title=""  MasterPageFile="~/EmploymentWeb.Master" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="employeeborowes.aspx.cs" Inherits="Employment_Site.employeeborowes" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AllContent" runat="server">

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 105px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Employee Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 178px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="empname" runat="server" Width="165px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style2" style="width: 61px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnsearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="70px" 
                    onclick="btnsearch_Click" />
            </td>
            <td class="style2" style="width: 72px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnclear" runat="server" onclick="btnclear_Click" Text="Clear" 
                    Width="70px" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 144px">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 105px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="4">
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"
 UpdateMode="Conditional"  >
 <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:GridView ID="empgrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="303px" 
                    onrowcommand="empgrid_RowCommand">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">

                            <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:HiddenField ID="EmployeeID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>'  />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>

                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
                                CommandName="UpdateEmployee" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                </asp:GridView>

                </ContentTemplate>
                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 105px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 178px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style2" style="width: 61px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style2" style="width: 72px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 144px">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 105px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 178px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style2" style="width: 61px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style2" style="width: 72px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 144px">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

   </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Unsolicited advice: (1) lose the update panel, (2) build an ASP web API, (3) use a javascript object to render a table. That third one is optional as I do enjoy the simplicity of gridview. Regarding your question, I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
HiddenField empID = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("EmployeeID");
Session["Employee"] = empID.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
   Use Response.Redirect("UpdateEmployee.aspx",false); 
instead of Response.Redirect("UpdateEmployee.aspx");

This is because of the way Redirect and session variables work.
When you create a new session an volatile cookie is set on the client that contains the session token. On all subsequent requests, and as long as the server session and the client cookie have not expired, ASP.NET can look at this cookie and find the right session.

what Redirect does is to send a special header to the client so that it asks the server for a different page than the one it was waiting for.

Hope this helps!!